# LINQ to Entities - assigning many to many relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

I need to write something like the following, which creates some Table1 <==> Table2 relations.

```
table1.Table2 = context.Table2.Where(t => t.ID.In(arrayOfIDs))
```

Table1 and Table2 have a many to many relationship, eg they have a joining table in the database. How do I do it?

**edit:**

A fuller example:

```
internal void UpdateMedia(int mediaID, int[] catagoryIDs)
{
    using (Data.EFEntities context = new Data.EFEntities())
    {
        Data.Media media = context.Media.Single(m => m.MediaID == mediaID);

        media.Category = context.Category.Where(cat => cat.CategoryID.In(catagoryIDs));

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, but should show what I am trying to achieve. (Entity Framework 4 btw)

Comment: Are you asking how can you make join? Please clarify more

Comment: I wish to assign the specified Table2 rows to Table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
internal void UpdateMedia(int mediaID, int[] catagoryIDs)
{
    using (Data.EFEntities context = new Data.EFEntities())
    {
        Data.Media media = context.Media.Single(m => m.MediaID == mediaID);

        foreach(var category in context.Category.Where(cat => catagoryIDs.Contains(cat.CategoryID))
        {
            media.Categories.Add(category);                
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this is the way to go.  After trying to add code to remove existing categories and avoiding adding categories that already exist, I gave up and wrote a stored procedure to do it.  It bugs me at how awkward it is to do stuff like this using entity framework.